# Entity Framework added 3 foreign keys for 1 relationship

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a simple User Class

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual ApplicationUser LoginID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string JobTitle { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(UserRole.Standard)]
    public UserRole Role { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    public string Email { get { return LoginID.Email; } }

    public bool HasAccess(UserRole TargetRole)
    {
     //Non-relevant logic
    }
}
```

And I also have a Company class defined as

```
public class Company
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(length: 70)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<User> Employees { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CompanyEmailDomain> Domains { get; set; }
        public ICollection<User> Managers { get { return Employees.Where(x => x.Role == UserRole.Manager).ToList(); } }
    }
```

However, when I run the `add-migration` command, it tries to add 3 Foreign keys on the User table to the Company table. Can anyone tell me why this would be the case?

```
AddColumn("dbo.Users", "Company_ID", c => c.Int());
AddColumn("dbo.Users", "Company_ID1", c => c.Int());
AddColumn("dbo.Users", "Company_ID2", c => c.Int());
```

Comment: Which EF version is this?

Comment: @GertArnold I'm using EF6. This is my first project using EF, so there may very well be a fundamental misunderstanding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework simply counts the associations between `User` and `Company`. It detects three of them:

1. `Company` in `User`.
2. `Employees` in `Company`
3. `Managers` in `Company`

They're all `1-n` (`Company - User`), so, EF concludes, `User` needs three foreign keys.

*You* know that `Managers` is a computed property. In fact, the property shouldn't even be be mapped. You should add the `[NotMapped]` attribute to it or map it as ignored by the fluent mapping API.

Also, *you* know that `User.Company` and `Company.Employees` are two ends of one association. But because of the two `ICollection<User>` properties, EF doesn't know which one to choose for the other end (the *inverse end*) of `User.Company`.

Now if you unmap `Company.Managers`, EF will see two properties --`User.Company` and `Company.Employees`-- and assume they belong together. So by unmapping one property, only one foreign key will be created.

Comment: Brilliant, cheers. I was wondering how EF knew which properties to map to the database. Now I know you have to explicitly exclude them